# React - Set state object using args

Tags: reactjs

I have an object saved in a state I am trying to create a function to update parts of the object.

```
function removeError(val) {
    setPersonsState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      val: "",
    }));
  }
```

I have tried to pass val to the object key to update it.

`onClick={removeError('Bob')}`

Where Bob replaces val to update in the object. Sorry if terminology is bad.

Comment: Whenever you want to pass a parameter to a onClick handler function, you need to return that function in the form of arrow function. Like this - `onClick = { () => removeError('Bob') }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should change it to be in the following way, sine you don't want to change a key named `val`, but the key with name equal to the value of `val`

```
function removeError(val) {
    setPersonsState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [val]: "",
    }));
}
```

And, as suggested in the comments by @RoshanKanwar, also the click handler is not correct, it should be

```
onClick = {() => removeError('Bob')}
```